# Identification of a plane transformation

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

We have four points  $ A , B, A', B'$ in the Euclidean plane.
Let $O$ be the center of the direct similitude $s: AB \mapsto A'B'$.

Now, the points $A', B, B'$ being fixed, how can I find the expression in terms of complex numbers of the plane transformation $A \mapsto O$  ?

It should be an homography but I can't find its exact analytical form...
Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm confused... so I'm asking some basic questions.  $s$ maps $A$ to $A'$ and $B$ to $B'$, right?  Why would $A$ go to $O$?  I can't seem to scrape up what the center of a similitude is either.

Comment: Yes $s(A) =A'$ ans $s(B) =B'$.

Comment: OK so you're talking about a transformation other than $s$ that sends $A$ to $O$ and fixes the rest. What's the center of a similitude now?

Comment: Is it the fixed point of the dilation?

Comment: Let me defined more précisely the center $O$ of $s$. If the similitude is the composition of an affine homothety with center $O$ and power $k$ with a rotation $r$ of center $O$, then the center of $s$ is the point $O$ such that for every point $M$ of the plane, we have $\overrightarrow{Os(M)} =kr(\overrightarrow{OM}) $.

Comment: In that case, the center $O$ is the unique fixed point of $s$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{C}$ a direct similitude is $z \mapsto h(z) = \alpha z + \beta$ with $\alpha \neq 0, 1$.Let $a, a', b, b'$ the complex affixes of $A, A', B, B'$. Let us suppose $A \neq B \iff a \neq b$. The center $O$ (affixe $o$ ) is such that $h(o)= o \iff o = \frac{\beta}{1- \alpha}$. Now $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are defined by $h(a)= a'$ and $h(b) = b'$ hence $o = \frac{a b' - a'b}{a-b - (a'-b')}$. The map $a \mapsto o$ is an homography.